# JavaScript parallel promises: when one promise start and another promise end?

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

So, in my project I have `response-interceptor` that catch the response with `401` status code and then requested new `JWT`-token and retry this request.

Code:

```js
export class TokenFlushInterceptor extends TokenRefreshInterceptor {
    private awaitingPromise: Promise<any> | null;

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.awaitingPromise = null;
    }

    private async retry(response: Response, requestOptions: RequestInit, token: string): Promise<Response> {
        return fetch(response.url, {
            ...requestOptions,
            headers: {
                ...requestOptions!.headers,
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
        });
    }

    public async intercept(response: Response, requestOptions?: RequestInit): Promise<Response> {
        if (AUTH_RESPONSE_CODES.UNAUTHORIZED === response.status) {
            if (this.awaitingPromise) {
                const newToken = await this.awaitingPromise;

                const retryRequest = await this.retry(response, requestOptions!, newToken);

                this.awaitingPromise = null;

                return retryRequest;
            }

            const store = ReduxService.serverReduxStore;
            if (!store) {
                return response;
            }

            this.awaitingPromise = store.dispatch(flushToken);
            const newToken = await this.awaitingPromise;


            const retryRequest = await this.retry(response, requestOptions!, newToken);

            this.awaitingPromise = null;
            return retryRequest;
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

so, I'm saving the promise of `flushToken`-request in the class-field in the case of parallel request and if I have another parallel-request that get `401` that another request waiting till the `flushToken`-promise end and then repeats himself.

But, I think this code having issue:

```js
this.awaitingPromise = store.dispatch(flushToken);
const newToken = await this.awaitingPromise;
this.awaitingPromise = null;

const retryRequest = await this.retry(response, requestOptions!, newToken);

this.awaitingPromise = null;
return retryRequest;
```

so, we have two asyn requests in `Promise.all`

`X-request` getting `401` first than `Y-request`, so in interceptor we setting field `awaitingPromise` to `flushToken`-request  (`Y-request` still pending), then we do retry X-request (`Y-request` done and get 401), so in `Y-request` context we are in this part of code:

```js
         if (this.awaitingPromise) {
                const newToken = await this.awaitingPromise;
                this.awaitingPromise = null;

                const retryRequest = await this.retry(response, requestOptions!, newToken);

                this.awaitingPromise = null;

                return retryRequest;
         }
```

`awaitingPromise` still having `flushToken` from `X-request`, so we go further, (but in `X-request` context we already set `awaitingPromise` to null.

So question is: we are getting the null in `awaitingPromise` the part of code bellow or not? Condition in `if`-statements `true` in the moment when `flushToken`-pending, but when we in `if`-statement branch `flushToken` is fullfiled and in `if`-statement `awaitingPromise` is null.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking. `so, we have two asyn requests in Promise.all` I don't see any `Promise.all` im your code. And I don't see the propose of `awaitingPromise` as it is only used in `intercept`.

Comment: why would you need to do `this.awaitingPromise = null;` ... since the code in that fragment basically runs in order - also, where do you think you have "parallel" promises?

Comment: I show you only interceptor code.

@t.niese 

@JaromandaX

I mean imagine the case when you have two parallel request (for example in `Promise.all`) and that two requests intercepted by the my response interceptor. And what is goin on when first request getting 401 faster than second.

Comment: If I simplify: 

Can there be a situation in JS when:

```

if (flag) {
  // some action
  // and here the parallel promise changes the value of the flag variable so that already 
   inside the if branch, flag will be equal to null
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everyone, sorry for my bad english. I have the answer:

JS is asynchronous and not multi-threaded so there can't be a case where execution ends up inside a condition and the value changes